# notify_url not working anymore in PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I have the following payment form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" id="online-store-paypal">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="kae@kvsites.ie">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Purchase made from www.kvsites.ie">
  <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="6">
  <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" value="http://www.kvsites.ie/contact-us/Login?onlinestore_iid=6" name="return">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.kvsites.ie/ww.plugins/online-store/verify/paypal.php">
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="IC_Sample">
  <input type="image" style="width:68px;height:23px;" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but23.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with payPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
  <img width="1" height="1" alt="" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif">
</form>
```

The relevant line is this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://www.kvsites.ie/ww.plugins/online-store/verify/paypal.php">
```

When I access it directly, it (obviously) is registered in my web server's access log.

When I actually /use/ the form, though, the payment goes through successfully, but the IPN does not appear in PayPal's IPN history page, and does not appear in Apache's logs.

This is something that worked perfectly for months, and only recently has stopped working completely.

Comment: Same problem. Worked for over a year, stopped working today... Searching for a solution/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paypal IPN notification are down at the moment. [See on Twitter](https://twitter.com/search?q=paypal%20down).